# What is difference between , and +

Tags: javascript

In string concatenation we can use following:

```
var a = 'Something', b = 'Something else';
console.log(a + b);
```

vs

```
console.log(a , b);
```

Is there any difference here?

**Update**

I haven't got the answers I was expecting for. Let me elaborate a bit more. If I run this code in chrome console. I get different results:

```
var a = {a: 'aa'};
var b = {b: 'bb'};

console.log(a, b);
Object {a: "aa"} Object {b: "bb"}

console.log(a + b);
[object Object][object Object]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, `+` can be used to [concatenate strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/String_Operators). Here, `+` joins `a` and `b` together.

```
console.log("Hello" + "world") // "Helloworld"
```

Using a `,` instead logs both of the variables, separated by a space:

```
console.log("Hello", "world") // "Hello world"
```

The difference is obvious if we use numbers instead of strings:

```
console.log(1 + 1) // 2
console.log(1, 1)  // 1 1
```

#### Edit:

> Updated my question, could you please explain this behaviour.

When you use `+` on objects, these are first converted into a string and then concatenated. When converted to a string, an object becomes `[object Object]`. Using `+` to concatenate two objects will output `[object Object][object Object]`.

Separating the objects with a comma logs each individual object (and all its methods and properties). No string conversion occurs.

Comment: Updated my question, could you please explain this behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

`a + b` concatenates two strings (or adds two numbers).
`,` in `console.log(a, b)` passes two separate parameters to the function, in `var a, b` declares two variables.

`,` is a separator with different uses depending on the context, `+` is the concatenation/addition operator.

Compare:

```
Math.max(1 + 2) // 3, because you're passing one argument
Math.max(1, 2)  // 2, because you're passing two arguments
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any difference here?

Yes... they are totally and **completely** different. While `a + b` adds two variables (implemented as concatenation in the case of strings), `a, b` is *not* string concatenation. You're simply passing two arguments to `console.log`, which accepts an arbitrary number of arguments and outputs them.

Comment: Is this really true? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console.log says arguments' string representation are appended

Comment: @bruce Yes, it's true. At least in webkit, you can happily run `console.log('what', {name: 'bob'})`, and you get the expected output, rather than `'what [Object object]'`, which is what would happen if it were concatenating variables.

Answer (score 1):

```
 console.log(2+3); //concatenates two strings
 console.log(2,3); // separate strings


OUTPUT

5
2 3
```